# Cómo validar que la entrada es numérica

Tags: c#

Estoy realizando un ejercicio en el que tengo que leer un número, pero el ejercicio me prohíbe usar el tipo `int`. ¿Cómo hago que mi programa solo acepte un número sin usar `int`?

Éste es el código que tengo hasta el momento:

```
Console.WriteLine("Escoge un ataque para tu monstruo: ");
string a = Console.ReadLine();
short decision = Convert.ToInt16(a);
try
{

}
catch (Exception)
{
  Console.WriteLine("Solo ingresa números por favor!");
}
```

Comment: Deberías añadir algo más de información a la pregunta: ¿Por qué no puedes usar el tipo (que no clase) `int`? ¿Es una restricción del ejercicio o es por algún error que recibes? ¿Qué has buscado/intentado hasta el momento? Lee [ask] y completa el [tour] donde encontrarás más información y recomendaciones para mejorar tus preguntas (y ganarás tu primera medalla).

Comment: Es solo por el ejercicio me lo prohíbe, no puedo usar el tipo int

Comment: No logro comprender con que no puedes usar la clase int, int es un tipo no una clase y si metes tu código dentro del try vas a lograr en parte lo que quieres, pues va a mandar una exception cuando intentes convertir un caracter que no sea número.

Comment: ¿Puedes usar otros tipos numéricos como `long`? ¿Y qué es lo que enseñaron en la clase antes del ejercicio? (para intentar comprender el contexto del ejercicio, porque ya tienes un `ToInt16`que debería hacer lo que quieres)

Answer (score 1):

Deberías usar **Regex** si se te permite, con esto puedes hacer que compruebe si el string dado está formado por números únicamente. Ejemplo:

```
Console.WriteLine("Escoge un ataque para tu monstruo: ");
string a = Console.ReadLine();

Regex regex = new Regex("[^0-9]+");

if (regex.IsMatch(a))
{ 
    //es un número
}
else
{
Console.WriteLine("Solo ingresa números por favor!");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

También podes usar

```
tuString.All(char.IsDigit);
```

Va a retornar `true` si en la variable `tuString` hay un número entero (en caso de tener coma/punto será falso)

Para usar este método tenes que tener en cuenta 2 situaciones.

1. Si `tuString` es `null` se producirá un `ArgumentNullException`
2. Si `tuString` es una cadena vacía, retornará true

Respuesta basada en la de [Kunal Goel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26465325/5213794) en StackOverflow en inglés

Answer (score 1):

Entiendo que es algún tipo de trabajo escolar y de ahí la restricción de no usar `int`.

Una posible solución es usar el ascii de la entrada para comprobar que los caracteres son numéricos. Todo aquel caracter que sea menor que `0` o mayor que `9` no es un dígito, y hace que el bucle se repita.

```
bool valido;
do
{
    valido = true;
    Console.WriteLine("Escoge un ataque para tu monstruo: ");
    string entrada = Console.ReadLine();


    foreach (char c in entrada)
    {
        if (c < '0' || c > '9')
        {
            valido = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!valido)
        Console.WriteLine("Solo ingresa números por favor!");
} while (!valido);
```

Answer (score 0):

Tal vez este código te sirva:

```
Console.WriteLine("Escoge un ataque para tu monstruo: ");
string a = Console.ReadLine();
int num;
if (int.TryParse(a, out num))
{
    Console.WriteLine("El número ingresado es {0}", num);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Solo ingresa números por favor!");
}
```

Comment: Hola Daniel. Bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] y [answer] para aprender más del funcionamiento de este sitio y como hacer buenas respuestas. Se agradece tu aportacion pero sería de mas calidad y más util para el OP y futuros usuarios si la editas para añadir más explicación. Un saludo

Comment: Actualmente esta respuesta es érronea (y cuando él la hizo) porque le prohiben usar `int`